How to resume suspended installation of SageMath on Ubuntu 24.04?
SageMath has been removed from the APT on Ubuntu 24.04, so I was installing it as per the instructions written at https://sagemanifolds.obspm.fr/install_ubuntu.html.
I was able to run the last command MAKE="make -j4" make to build it which ran for almost an hour. Then it froze as shown in the screenshot.


The script worked on my Ubuntu 24.04 desktop.  Installed the extra functionality, did not install any ./configure suggestions, just let them download and build. What extras did you install before the "make"?  Took 91 minutes to run make -j10. sage successfully runs. Better than the miniforge/pip sage install which took much more space for an old version, which I eventually removed. How much free space on your disk?

You might fsck the filesystem, to ensure no errors, then if you have enough free space (about 9GB for sage stuff which I put on a data partition, more for the os packages),  just resubmit the make command again -- it should pretty quickly skip over the parts it has already run.

Thank you so much for your comment. I followed yuor suggestions and resubmitted the make. It resumed the installation and took 192 minutes to finish.
